# python code turns number value in bracket [number] value and returns non numerical error

Tags: python, pandas

I feel like I could not search this as properly, as I usually do, since I do not know for sure what this element (n) was turned into [n].

I believe it is a dict key but I am not sure.

I entered the following code:

```
def get_quantile_count(group, q=0.5):
    group=group.sort_index(by='prop', ascending=False)
    return group.prop.cumsum().searchsorted(q) + 1
diversity= top1000.groupby(['year','sex']).apply(get_quantile_count)
diversity=diversity.unstack('sex')
```

`top1000.head()` returns:

```
       name sex  births  year      prop
year sex                                         
1880 F   0       Mary   F    7065  1880  0.077643
         1       Anna   F    2604  1880  0.028618
         2       Emma   F    2003  1880  0.022013
         3  Elizabeth   F    1939  1880  0.021309
         4     Minnie   F    1746  1880  0.019188
```

and `diversity.head()` returns

```
sex      F     M
year            
1880  [38]  [14]
1881  [38]  [14]
1882  [38]  [15]
1883  [39]  [15]
1884  [39]  [16]
```

I believe that since the values are in [brackets] when I run diversity.plot(title='stuff') I get the error :

```
TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot
```

Where are these square brackets creeping in?

Comment: [38] is a list. [38].pop() is one way to get the single number that it contains

Comment: Thanks for the reply. At what point in the code did it become a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's to do with [`searchsorted`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.searchsorted.html) which your function `get_quantile_count` calls when `return`ing.

It always returns [a list](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists). See this example from the docs:

> ```
> >>> x = pd.Series([1, 2, 3])
> >>> x
> 0    1
> 1    2
> 2    3
> dtype: int64
> >>> x.searchsorted(4)
> array([3])
> ```

As a rather unsatisfying workaround to this fact, you could just change the last line of the function to:

```
return group.prop.cumsum().searchsorted(q)[0] + 1
```

Or, if you don't want to edit the function for some reason, you can always extract the first element of each of those lists with [`applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) which applies [an arbitrary function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890128/why-python-lambdas-are-useful) to each element of a `DataFrame`:

```
In []: df
Out[]: 
         F     M
year            
1880  [38]  [14]
1881  [38]  [14]
1882  [38]  [15]
1883  [39]  [15]
1884  [39]  [16]
In []: df.applymap(lambda x: x[0])
Out[]: 
       F   M
year        
1880  38  14
1881  38  14
1882  38  15
1883  39  15
1884  39  16
```